# External drives will not automount until I log out and in again

Tags: usb, automount

Issue: When I boot up Ubuntu external USB drives such as my external HD and thumb drives, as well as the Windows partition are not recognized or mounted until I log out from the user and log in again (As the same user or a different one). This does not affect USB mice, keyboard, Wacom tablet or printer.

This issue has been happening since v12 I am currently on v.15.04 with a fresh install. Strangely at some point a routine update seemed to fix it but since I mangled the installation in an unrelated misadventure it's back

laptop Asus x59SL series, duo t5800 cpu, 4g ram ATI, Mobility Radeon HD3470 running gallium. 64bit ubuntu 15.04

I was able to edit fstab to mount the external and windows but I'd like to be able to plug thumb drives too, and if I forget the re-login ritual it can be annoying.

That said I've solved a separate issue with being unable to put the system to sleep so I no longer need to reboot as often, so this probably won't be as much as a bother, I'm happy to say I'm running linux full time now!

I have checked dconf settings: media handling is checked for automount & automount open

The password keyring doesn't seem to make a difference - I thought it might because my initial login is password free, but if I set it to ask for a password it still doesn't automount

Flashing the bios may or may not help but I'm not keen on doing it for fear of bricking my machine which would be inconvenient to replace.

Any suggestions welcome. It's not a major problem but it would be nice to fix it, it's the last lingering issue I have with ubuntu on this laptop (Aside from the ATI catalyst drivers but that's on them)

Output of `ls /dev/sd*` as requested

```
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdd1  
/dev/sda1  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda6  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdd   /dev/sdd2
```

the last 3 (/dev/sdd /dev/sdd1  /dev/sdd2) appear on mounting a single thumb drive, don't know if that's the expected behaviour (thumbdrive is a single partition AFAIK).

output of `ls /dev/sd*` when not automounting

```
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdc  
/dev/sda1  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda6  /dev/sdb1
```

output of `df -vh` with everything mounted

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev            2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev  
tmpfs           396M   41M  355M  11% /run  
/dev/sda6       134G   73G   54G  58% /  
tmpfs           2,0G   21M  2,0G   2% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock  
tmpfs           2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs  
tmpfs           396M   84K  396M   1% /run/user/1000  
/dev/sdc1       932G  730G  202G  79% /media/nestor/TOSHIBA EXT  
/dev/sda2       150G  119G   31G  80% /media/nestor/VistaOS  
/dev/sdd1       1,1G  1,1G     0 100% /media/nestor/Ubuntu 15.04 amd64
```

(The last 3 are of course missing when the automount isn't working)

Comment: Please add the output of "ls /dev/sd*" with your thumb drives plugged in

Comment: Done, I edited in the output with the system working normally if you want me to give you the output when it fails to automount I'll do it later, currently rendering a frame on blender so I can't reboot right now. Thanks!

Comment: The last 3 appearing is normal for a thumb drive with 2 partitions, so if yours have 2 partitions, then that's normal.  When it fails to mount, please add the output of that same command again.

Comment: And also include the output of "df -vh" when it is working and everything is mounted.

Comment: Done, I'm not 100% on the partitions on the thumbdrive but a friend formatted it and installed the ubuntu iso I used to reinstall so I think it has only one partition, thanks @Daniel

Comment: Strange.  The ones you say don't show up DO appear in /dev/.  Will they manually mount?

Comment: I don't know anything about automount specifically, but does it report success for the drive, but then the drive doesn't mount or immediately unmounts?